# How do I make something loop 10 times then continue in batch?

Tags: loops, batch-file

In batch, I want to run something 10 times and then `goto continue`.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? I recommend looking at the documentation from `for /?` if you need some place to start.

Comment: @SomethingDark I've tried `:e set count=%count%+1 if %count% GEQ 10 goto e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo before

set i=0
:loop1

echo something 10 times

set /a i+=1
if !i!==10 goto continue

goto loop1
:continue

echo after

exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is a `for /L` loop.

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,10) do (
    rem your code here
)
goto continue
```

The format for a `for /L` loop is (`start`,`step`,`end`), so (1,1,10) means start at 1 and count to 10 by 1s.

Comment: Gives me a syntax error if I use it like `for /L %%A in (1,1,10) do (
 set randomfile=%RANDOM%
 echo xfileav%RANDOM%to%randomfile% > %randomfile%
 copy %randomfile% %vdefdir%
 del "%randomfile%"
)`

Comment: @MarkieJonesWTF - Code doesn't appear correctly in comments, so I'm only guessing where you're putting newlines, but you probably need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!randomfile!` instead of `%randomfile%` since the variable was created inside of the code block.